# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session has been closed; further changes are illegal

Tags: android, capture, android-camera2, camera2

i know there are a lot of questions concerning exception above, but still couldn't find the answer and decided to ask by myself.
The exception is thrown sometimes, during capturing with camera2, sometimes going to background. 
Exception shows in the following line:

```
try {
    if ((null != mCaptureSession) && (isCameraOpen)) {
        mState = STATE_PREVIEW;
        mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, mHandler);
    }
} catch (CameraAccessException e) {
    L.e("CameraLolipop --- CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback " + e);
}
```

on mCaptureSession.capture.... I tried to check also if mCaptureSession isReprocessable and it works for devices 23 and above. 
But couldn't do anything else for the rest.
Guys, please help to find a solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Here is the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session has been closed; further changes are illegal.
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.checkNotClosed(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:569)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.capture(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:152)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at android.hardware.camera2.dispatch.InvokeDispatcher.dispatch(InvokeDispatcher.java:39)
at android.hardware.camera2.dispatch.HandlerDispatcher$1.run(HandlerDispatcher.java:65)
```

Comment: can you post the error log?

Comment: sure, here it is:

Comment: Did you solve it? Can't we see the whole source code?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is use for api >=23 Camera2 with isReprocessable() method, for api<23 use Camera1.
Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

I facing the same problem, I solved with hide the texture onPause and send a thread to finish close the camera before it change/close and in the resume set visible the texture. I hope this can help you.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mTextureView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    closeCamera();
    closeBackgroundThread();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mTextureView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    openBackgroundThread();
    if(mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
        openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
    } else {
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
    }
}
```